# App references non-public selectors in payload/AppName:consume

Tags: xcode, app-store, adobe, ios8, adobe-analytics

I am facing issue where it shows warning below while uploading an App to `Appstore`

```
App references non-public selectors in payload/AppName:consume
```

Any help is appreciated.

I have uploaded the app with above warning, will my App be rejected by Apple or not?

**consume:** is the method used in Omniture Library and How can I overcome from this issue.

[image]

Comment: What does this `consume:` method look like?

Comment: Yah Its a method :
- (void) consume: (NSString *) content

Comment: I wonder how the validation process knows that selector is non-public?  It doesn't follow the convention of using a leading `_` character.

Comment: Is there any way to search consume method in code except project navigator search bar

Comment: I don't know whether I'm right or wrong, but I read that message as saying there's something **inside** the `consume:` method that it doesn't like rather than the method itself.  (Which is why I asked my first question, assuming you'd show its implementation code.)

Comment: Its implementation is hidden as it is from the Third party library(Omniture).

Comment: consume: is the method used in Omniture Library and How can I overcome from this issue.

Comment: I am getting error itunes store operation failed the app references non-public selectors in payload : setResult; taskWithResult